# Facing audio issues in pop os linux

Tags: linux, audio, pulseaudio, alsa, pipewire

i am facing audio issue in pop os linux that when i plug in earphones, only i am able to hear audio with noise in between some of the times and earphones mic does not work at all. But it is working fine in windows after a chipset driver install in windows.Can someone help with this audio issue.

```
lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Pop
Description:    Pop!_OS 22.04 LTS
Release:    22.04
Codename:   jammy
```

Comment: Hi , anyone please help